# Rotation of Bitmap at any Angle

Tags: android, math, bitmap, rotation

I have some confusion for the bitmap rotation if I am not wrong then we can say Bitmap is set of pixels array. For example given below array consider as my image.

```
123 456 789
453 782 964 
145 642 754
```

This image rotate at 90 degree very simple we can take the transpose of this matrix and we can get required output but if I want to rotate this array at any angle then what to do? If you consider bitmap as container so one or more question arise how to rotate container at any degree?  May refer some site and providing mathematical equations for the rotation at any degree like

```
x1 = x*cos(angle) + y*sin(angle) 
y1 = y*cos(angle) - x*sin(angle)
```

This new x and y give coordinates in floating point then one or more question arise it is possible translation of the bitmap using floating point value? I am totally confused for the bitmap rotation can anyone help me for this confusion.
I can do logical work look like this

 
[image]

Comment: It may be a difficulty with english here-  what are you actually asking?  Your math is right and I can tell you know the linear algebra behind a rotation matrix.  What I can't tell is what you're actually having difficulty with.

Comment: It's alittle more complicated when you start talking about discrete pixels. You have to approximate float values to pixels, and smoothen it somehow

Comment: @GabeSechan, i want to make new bitmap and above my image array how i can rotate this array at 45' degree look like above image. all the solution give direct use of API like Matrix and setRoation but how i can do roation mathematically.

Comment: A matrix is doing it mathematically. You build a matrix in the form {{cos x, sin x}, {-sin x, cos x}}. Then you multiply each pixel location as a vector by that matrix, and it gets you the new location.  But by using the matrix you can do it on ultra fast gpu hardware.

Comment: Why do you want to do it "mathematically"? The `Matrix` class uses native transformations, it would be pretty hard to beat it, performance-wise.

Comment: @npace as computer engineer i thing i want to know what is actually doing matrix class if you use matrix class is well and good but make your self to aware with actuall logic behind that.

Comment: If you rotate image like that then image Aspect must be change as you shown in your image .I suggest you can rotate image using ImageView. and should calculate image height and width previously so you can  find x and y position.